# Retrieve data from excel "csv format" similar to linq take skip

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I need to retrieve specific portion from CSV file depend on row number

[image]

Ex: from row number `5` to `12`

I'm using `OleDbConnection` and tried to use this query:

```
select * from [sheet1.csv$A5:A12]
```

But it doesn't work.

C# Code:

```
 var filename = @"C:\Users\A\Desktop\passwords.csv";
        var connString = string.Format(
            @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""",
            Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)
        );
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var query = "SELECT * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(filename) + "$A5:A12]";
            using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
            {
                var ds = new DataSet("CSV File");
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
```

Error

```
The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'passwords.csv$A5:A12'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
```

Comment: Please expand on 'doesn't work' - post the error and all the other code

Comment: If its a real CSV, its just a text file and you can open it with normal text functions. Just skip the first 5 carriage returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows an example using both StreamReader (its just a text file remember) and the Jet driver:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27802/Using-OleDb-to-Import-Text-Files-tab-CSV-custom

So lose the `"$A5:A12]` bit, and use a DataReader instead. Then call the Read method 5 times to move to the fifth row.

I am not a C# programmer just a good googler.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `OleDbConnection` 
i'm just use [File Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filename);
var rows = lines.Skip(4).Take(8);
```